# Tab delimited String to arrays

Tags: java, arrays, string, csv

What I am trying to achieve is read data off an Excel Sheet (saved in Txt, tab delimited), row by row and each individual column is different data that I want to store in an array.

I tried different ways.. I even downloaded CSVReader class off the internet and it didnt work.
At least this time its reading real Characters and not jiberish.

The version I have now is uses bufferedReader and String Tokenizer. 
But it's not reading properly.

Here's the code:

```
     import java.io.BufferedReader;
     import java.io.BufferedWriter;
     import java.io.File;
     import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
     import java.io.FileReader;
     import java.io.FileWriter;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.util.StringTokenizer;

     import com.csvreader.CsvReader;

     import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVReader;


     public class excelToText{
     public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    try
    {

        //csv file containing data
          BufferedReader CSVFile = new BufferedReader(new          FileReader("C:/Users/nhajjar/workspace/MB/src/yoyo.txt"));


          // Read first line.
          String dataRow; 
          int lineNumber = 0; 


          while ((dataRow = CSVFile.readLine() )!= null)
          {
                String [] dataArray;
                lineNumber++; 



                String delimiter = "\t";
                /* given string will be split by the argument delimiter provided. */
                dataArray = dataRow.split(delimiter);
                /* print substrings */
```

//                  for(int i =0; i < dataArray.length ; i++)
//                      System.out.println(dataArray[i]);

```
                String PrinterName = dataArray[0];
                String Model = dataArray[1];
                String IP = dataArray[2];
                String Location = dataArray[3];
                String Department = dataArray[4];
                String PrimServer = dataArray[5];
                String SecServer = dataArray[6];
                String ShareName = dataArray[7];
                String GroupNamePrefix = dataArray[8];
                String GroupNameSuffix = dataArray[9];
                String GroupNameFinal = dataArray[10];
                String WSPPrefix = dataArray[11];
                String WSPFull = dataArray[12];
                String PrimWSP = dataArray[13];
                String SecWSP = dataArray[14];

              System.out.println("PrinterName is : " + PrinterName);
                System.out.println("Model is : " + Model);
                System.out.println("IP is : " + IP);
                System.out.println("Location is : " + Location);
                System.out.println("Department is : " + Department);
                System.out.println("PrimServer is : " + PrimServer);
                System.out.println("SecServer is : " + SecServer);
                System.out.println("ShareName is : " + ShareName);
                System.out.println("GroupNamePrefix is : " + GroupNamePrefix);
                System.out.println("GroupNameSuffix is : " + GroupNameSuffix);
                System.out.println("GroupNameFinal is : " + GroupNameFinal);
                System.out.println("WSPPrefix is : " + WSPPrefix);
                System.out.println("WSPFull is : " + WSPFull);
                System.out.println("PrimWSP is : " + PrimWSP);
                System.out.println("PrimWSP is : " + PrimWSP);
                System.out.println("SecWSP is : " + SecWSP);



                /*//writing file for ones that were not sent out. 
                  File file = new File("write.txt");
                  BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
                  */

            }




            CSVFile.close();

        }   catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   catch(Exception e)          {
          System.out.println("Exception while reading/writing csv file: " + e);                   
        }// end Exceptions 

  }// end try block 
     }
```

input is :

```
    Printer name    Model   IP  Location    Department  Primary Server  Secondary Server    Share Name
    Boundary Sprinter Techs Lexmark E360dn      Boundary    Sprinter    s173m928site    s173mho1site    928-Sprinter-techs-L-E360dn
    Boundary Sprinter Xerox 7232    Xerox WorkCentre 7232       Boundary    Sprinter    s173m928site    s173mho1site    928-Sprinter-WC7232
    Boundry Parts   HP LaserJet P2055dn     Boundary    Parts   s173m928site    s173mho1site    928-Parts-LJ-P2055dn
    Boundry Sales   HP Color LaserJet CP4005        Boundary    Sales   s173m928site    s173mho1site    928-Sales-Main-CP4005
    Boundry Techs East  HP LaserJet P3015       Boundary    Techs East  s173m928site    s173mho1site    928-Techs-east-LJ-P3015
    Boundry Techs West  Lexmark E352dn      Boundary    Techs West  s173m928site    s173mho1site    928-Techs-west-L-E352dn
    Concord     Lexmark E360dn      Concord         s173mho1site    
    Dundas Parts    Xerox WorkCentre 7232       Dundas  Parts   s173m910site    s173mho1site    910-Parts-WC-7232
    Dundas Preowned Xerox WorkCentre 7425       Dundas  Preowned    s173m910site    s173mho1site    910-PreOwned-WC-7425
    Dundas Sales 2nd Floor  HP Color LaserJet CP4025        Dundas  Sales   s173m910site    s173mho1site    910-Sales-2nd-CP4025
    Dundas Sales Main Floor HP Color LaserJet CP4025        Dundas  Sales   s173m910site    s173mho1site    910-Sales-Main-CP4025


output im getting is : 


PrinterName is : Printer name 
Model is : Model
IP is : IP
Location is : Location
Department is : Department
PrimServer is : Primary Server 
SecServer is : Secondary Server
ShareName is : Share Name
GroupNamePrefix is : Group Name Prefix
GroupNameSuffix is : Group Name Suffix
GroupNameFinal is : Group Name Final
WSPPrefix is : WSP Prefix
WSPFull is : WSP Full
PrimWSP is : Primary WSP
PrimWSP is : Primary WSP
SecWSP is : Secondary WSP


PrinterName is : Boundary Sprinter Techs
Model is : Lexmark E360dn
IP is : 53.254.177.138
Location is : Boundary
Department is : Sprinter
PrimServer is : s173m928site
SecServer is : s173mho1site
ShareName is : 928-Sprinter-techs-L-E360dn
GroupNamePrefix is : D173_PRINTER-
GroupNameSuffix is : 928-Sprinter-techs-L-E360dn
GroupNameFinal is : D173_PRINTER-928-Sprinter-techs-L-E360dn
WSPPrefix is : #;\D173\_GLOBALRESOURCES\GROUPS\Printers\
WSPFull is : #;\D173\_GLOBALRESOURCES\GROUPS\Printers\D173_PRINTER-928-Sprinter-techs-L-E360dn.wsp;D173_PRINTER-928-Sprinter-techs-L-E360dn
PrimWSP is : >;%;\\s173m928site.cambc.corpintra.net\928-Sprinter-techs-L-E360dn
PrimWSP is : >;%;\\s173m928site.cambc.corpintra.net\928-Sprinter-techs-L-E360dn
SecWSP is : ;>;%;\\s173mho1site.cambc.corpintra.net\928-Sprinter-techs-L-E360dn


PrinterName is : Boundary Sprinter Xerox 7232
Model is : Xerox WorkCentre 7232
IP is : 53.254.177.136
Location is : Boundary
Department is : Sprinter
PrimServer is : s173m928site
SecServer is : s173mho1site
ShareName is : 928-Sprinter-WC7232
GroupNamePrefix is : D173_PRINTER-
GroupNameSuffix is : 928-Sprinter-WC7232
GroupNameFinal is : D173_PRINTER-928-Sprinter-WC7232
WSPPrefix is : #;\D173\_GLOBALRESOURCES\GROUPS\Printers\
WSPFull is : #;\D173\_GLOBALRESOURCES\GROUPS\Printers\D173_PRINTER-928-Sprinter-WC7232.wsp;D173_PRINTER-928-Sprinter-WC7232
PrimWSP is : >;%;\\s173m928site.cambc.corpintra.net\928-Sprinter-WC7232
PrimWSP is : >;%;\\s173m928site.cambc.corpintra.net\928-Sprinter-WC7232
SecWSP is : ;>;%;\\s173mho1site.cambc.corpintra.net\928-Sprinter-WC7232


PrinterName is : Boundry Parts
Model is : HP LaserJet P2055dn
IP is : 53.254.193.222
Location is : Boundary
Department is : Parts
PrimServer is : s173m928site
SecServer is : s173mho1site
ShareName is : 928-Parts-LJ-P2055dn
GroupNamePrefix is : D173_PRINTER-
GroupNameSuffix is : 928-Parts-LJ-P2055dn
GroupNameFinal is : D173_PRINTER-928-Parts-LJ-P2055dn
WSPPrefix is : #;\D173\_GLOBALRESOURCES\GROUPS\Printers\
WSPFull is : #;\D173\_GLOBALRESOURCES\GROUPS\Printers\D173_PRINTER-928-Parts-LJ-P2055dn.wsp;D173_PRINTER-928-Parts-LJ-P2055dn
PrimWSP is : >;%;\\s173m928site.cambc.corpintra.net\928-Parts-LJ-P2055dn
PrimWSP is : >;%;\\s173m928site.cambc.corpintra.net\928-Parts-LJ-P2055dn
SecWSP is : ;>;%;\\s173mho1site.cambc.corpintra.net\928-Parts-LJ-P2055dn


PrinterName is : Boundry Sales
Model is : HP Color LaserJet CP4005
IP is : 53.254.193.117
Location is : Boundary
Department is : Sales
PrimServer is : s173m928site
SecServer is : s173mho1site
ShareName is : 928-Sales-Main-CP4005
GroupNamePrefix is : D173_PRINTER-
GroupNameSuffix is : 928-Sales-Main-CP4005
GroupNameFinal is : D173_PRINTER-928-Sales-Main-CP4005
WSPPrefix is : #;\D173\_GLOBALRESOURCES\GROUPS\Printers\
WSPFull is : #;\D173\_GLOBALRESOURCES\GROUPS\Printers\D173_PRINTER-928-Sales-Main-CP4005.wsp;D173_PRINTER-928-Sales-Main-CP4005
PrimWSP is : >;%;\\s173m928site.cambc.corpintra.net\928-Sales-Main-CP4005
PrimWSP is : >;%;\\s173m928site.cambc.corpintra.net\928-Sales-Main-CP4005
SecWSP is : ;>;%;\\s173mho1site.cambc.corpintra.net\928-Sales-Main-CP4005


PrinterName is : Boundry Techs East
Model is : HP LaserJet P3015
IP is : 53.254.193.220
Location is : Boundary
Department is : Techs East
PrimServer is : s173m928site
SecServer is : s173mho1site
ShareName is : 928-Techs-east-LJ-P3015
GroupNamePrefix is : D173_PRINTER-
GroupNameSuffix is : 928-Techs-east-LJ-P3015
GroupNameFinal is : D173_PRINTER-928-Techs-east-LJ-P3015
WSPPrefix is : #;\D173\_GLOBALRESOURCES\GROUPS\Printers\
WSPFull is : #;\D173\_GLOBALRESOURCES\GROUPS\Printers\D173_PRINTER-928-Techs-east-LJ-P3015.wsp;D173_PRINTER-928-Techs-east-LJ-P3015
PrimWSP is : >;%;\\s173m928site.cambc.corpintra.net\928-Techs-east-LJ-P3015
PrimWSP is : >;%;\\s173m928site.cambc.corpintra.net\928-Techs-east-LJ-P3015
SecWSP is : ;>;%;\\s173mho1site.cambc.corpintra.net\928-Techs-east-LJ-P3015


PrinterName is : Boundry Techs West
Model is : Lexmark E352dn
IP is : 53.254.193.221
Location is : Boundary
Department is : Techs West
PrimServer is : s173m928site
SecServer is : s173mho1site
ShareName is : 928-Techs-west-L-E352dn
GroupNamePrefix is : D173_PRINTER-
GroupNameSuffix is : 928-Techs-west-L-E352dn
GroupNameFinal is : D173_PRINTER-928-Techs-west-L-E352dn
WSPPrefix is : #;\D173\_GLOBALRESOURCES\GROUPS\Printers\
WSPFull is : #;\D173\_GLOBALRESOURCES\GROUPS\Printers\D173_PRINTER-928-Techs-west-L-E352dn.wsp;D173_PRINTER-928-Techs-west-L-E352dn
PrimWSP is : >;%;\\s173m928site.cambc.corpintra.net\928-Techs-west-L-E352dn
PrimWSP is : >;%;\\s173m928site.cambc.corpintra.net\928-Techs-west-L-E352dn
SecWSP is : ;>;%;\\s173mho1site.cambc.corpintra.net\928-Techs-west-L-E352dn
Exception while reading/writing csv file: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
```

NOTE: I TRUNCATED THE OUTPUT. THERES ALOT MORE OF THESE 'Null blocks'

Comment: "But it's not reading properly. " Can you be more specific? Do you have a question? What is the expected output? Why are you using " + " as your delimiters when the file is tab separated? Have you tried "\t" or using split("\t")?

Comment: It's obv not reading properly which is my problem. I can't figure out why. 
expected output is printer name, model, ip, location... to have the right values from the file.

Comment: The input you specify seems to not be a list of csv values, but rather a space/tab separated values. What is your question? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your title says CSV, but there are no commas in your input. Is the file really tab delimited?

Comment: When I originally saved the file with ".csv" extension, It was spitting out weird Characters. 
When I saved it under Txt format, it started reading real characters but not the right way.

Comment: The first thing I would fix is your delimiters because they don't make any sense to me.

Comment: Also, When I saved it under txt format, it tabed like that on its own.

Comment: The delimiter you use is (" + ") in your stringTokenizer. Is that intentional?

Comment: I searched up that delimiter. I originally had (" ") but that did nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your over complicating this. A CSV file has comma separated values. So your file data should look something like:

Line 1: Cell 1,Cell 2, Cell 3, Cell 4, etc...

Line 2: Cell 1 of row2, Cell 2 of row2, etc...

Your using a tab delimited file so you need to split on the tabs

```
//Read first line 
String dataRow;
int lineNumber = 0;
while((dataRow = CSVFile.readline()) != null)
{
    String [] dataArray;
    lineNumber++;
    String delimiter = "\t";
    dataArray = dataRow.split(delimiter); //Now dataArray contains all the tab delimited cells that were on line one of the .txt file
    //Start assigning the information to your variables since it is stored in dataArray
    String PrinterName = dataArray[0];//This would assign the first cell (row 1, column 1 in excel) that was read from the text file. From looking at your input this should be "Printer name"
    String Model = dataArray[1];
    String IP = dataArray[2];
    //etc...Assign the rest
    //Print your output
    //Do anything else you need to do
 }//end the while loop
```

Here are some sources:

http://www.java-examples.com/java-string-split-example

Note: This example is closer to what you are doing just use "\t" instead of ",":
http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/threads/17262/reading-in-a-.csv-file-and-loading-the-data-into-an-array

hope this helps

Comment: Crashed with 
Exception while reading/writing csv file: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7

Comment: I would look at the portion of code where you are inserting the data into the array. The error is just referring to you trying  to access a slot that doesn't exist yet. Are you exceding the size of your array?

Comment: My first guess would be this line of code: dataArray[i++] = tokens.nextToken(); //if i is 100 or greater you will be outside the bounds of the array since you declare with a size of 100 (array has indices of 0-99)

Comment: well, normally each cell contains no more than around 50 characters. I made it 100 because It was crashing when I was not declaring a size for the array. Perhaps bigger array ?

Comment: I am not referring the number of characters in a cell, I am referring to the number of cells you have. If you are creating tokens with "\t" and if you call tokens.countTokens() and it returns more then 100 (meaning you have more then 100 cells) this also means i is going to go over the bounds of the string array you declared. Declaring string[] dataArray = new String[100];//This allocates memory for you to store up to 100 strings (e.g. the contents of 100 cells), not 100 characters. I can explain further if this is unclear.

Comment: I left it with undeclare array size.

Comment: just like that:  String [] dataArray;
And its still giving me that error. Why is that?

Comment: Try doing this after StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(dataRow,"\t"); CODE STARTS HERE: int numberOfCells = tokens.countTokens(); System.out.println(numberOfCells); //CODE STOPS. This will let you know the number of cells you're finding in each line you are reading. If a number printed is larger then dataArray.Length this means your dataArray size is too small. If you have changed your code since you first posted your question it would be beneficial to repost the new code in your question.

Comment: I'm trying what u wrote with the split method. how to count to tokens in that casE? 
Check code up there.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little more?

Comment: @Nidale Please repost the code if it has changed and state any new issues since last week. Also if you could specify what you would like elaborated that would help me give you the information you are seeking, rather than an assumption of mine. Currently I don't know what progress you have made or what you are stuck on.

Comment: I did repost. input output is there.

Comment: I am getting an array out of bounds exceptions. when Array hits slot 7, it crashes. Why is it crashing at that point and how can I fix it?

Comment: I tried to trace it with eclipse but there is no obvious reason why it's crashing on me. the row starting with "concord" is like any other row. 
Checked the length of the array and the whole way, its 15.

Comment: The length 15 is correct, however is it possible that you have an empty spot in your input file. It would be two Tabs back to back like this example: Printer Name tab (Nothing here) tab Model ID tab More Info tab...etc If you split this you'd get a null or unaccessible spot in the array where the tab(nothing) tab is because there was nothing stored there. So check to see if you have any back to back tabs at the place in the input file where it is failing.

Comment: actually, isn't it that if a slot in the array is not populated, then its value is a random number?

Answer (score 0):

Tokens are divided only by spaces and pluses. That is because second parameter of `StringTokenizer` doesn't allow regexp. Try to use `"\t"` by which fields seem to be really separated.

By the way you do not really need 100 strings array for each row.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the `String.split()` function as this will greatly simplify your code.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend splitting the data yourself with the .split or StringTokenizer class.  They don't account for field quoting, etc...

Use a library like (as mentioned) OpenCSV, or StrTokenizer (part of commons-lang) to do the parsing for you.

StrTokenizer example using a tab delimited parser:

```
StrTokenizer tokenizer = StrTokenizer.getTSVInstance();    
while ( (line = ...) != null) {
    tokenizer.reset(line);
    String tokArray[] = tokenizer.getTokenArray();
}
```